# Import project in android studio Error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

When I try to import project (in-app purchase sample Android) in a android studio I am getting the following error.

Here is the error:

[image]

I am quite new to this Studio I am not aware how I resolve this.

Comment: post the link from where you downloaded it

Comment: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 @Nilabja

Comment: please any one give a solution